# Excel 2010 can't move down the first page break

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm in Page Break preview mode. I am trying to drag the page break down so more will fit on one page, but instead it just pulls down a new page break and tries to partition things into Page 1 / Page 2 / Page 3.

I just want to move the page break down.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the print area and excel will scale the contents you select to fit on a page. MS describes it [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/set-a-print-area-on-a-worksheet-HP010342418.aspx).

You can highlight everything that you want on a page and then go to the page layout tab and click `set print area`.